# vim shows code point of zero-width non-joiner character

Tags: keyboard-layout

vim (version 8.0) shows <200C> when I insert [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character via Persian keyboard.
[image]

Comment: Farsi support was unfortunately removed from Vim as of version 8.1.0932, since it was mostly unmaintained at that point... See [this commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/14184a3133b9a6ee5f711d493c04e41ba4fa7c2f#diff-25d902c24283ab8cfbac54dfa101ad31) that dropped it.

Comment: @filbranden Thanks